# Python - OOP Create different objects from config file

Tags: python, oop, configuration

I am facing OOP issues while parsing a config file and instanciate objects from different type. I wonder specifically about the responsibility for constructing and checking parameters from the configuration file.

Let's take an example, I want to instanciate Animals (abstract class) as well as Vehicles(abstract class) and I define subclasses for each (Dog, Cat -- Car, Plane). 
I have the following config file for example with a dog and a car :

```
animal: 
  type: cat
  size: 0.4 
  scream: miaou 

vehicle: 
  type: car
  motor: super3000
  size: 2.6
```

I created a Config object, responsible for parsing the config file and acquire the data in a dict. 
I then created factories responsible for checking the given parameters and for creating the objects, so that the client code looks like:

```
def main():
  animal = AnimalFactory.create_animal(config)
  vehicle = VehicleFactory.create_vehicle(config) 
  do_super_stuff(animal, vehicle)
```

Thus each factory has a dependency to the Config object : is that a bad practice? 
Is there a better way (or a more pythonic way) of doing this?